# Can perimeters be a factor for deciding whether one polygon lies inside another polygon

Tags: geometry

Suppose we have two polygons $P_1$ and $P_2$ with their coordinates given. Can we decide whether $P_1$ lies inside $P_2$ or vice versa just by measuring the perimeters?

Comment: Consider a "star"... Or a Koch island...  You may be able to get close with "bounding perimeter", but that probably takes a lot more work than just tallying up whether each point and each side lies within the other shape.

Answer (score 1):

First, obviously if $P_1$ encloses $P_2$ you can translate $P_2$ without changing its perimeter so it is now outside of $P_1$.

So I assume what you mean is: given two polygons, what do their relative perimeters say about whether $P_1$ can be made to enclose $P_2$ using rigid motions of the polygons?

The answer is nothing. $P_2$ might have very small perimeter (think one tiny square inside a big square) or very large perimeter (think of a small star with many points inside a large square -- as you keep adding more points, the perimeter of the star goes to infinity while the perimeter of the enclosing square stays fixed).

So although area places restrictions on what shapes can enclose what other shapes, perimeter does not give any useful information.

Comment: Thanks.so area is the deciding factor

Comment: is there any alternate method to do so??